# Update the php after deleting in database

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is The main Page where the user_list.php gets $txt to query "where Like".

```
<?php
      include_once('dbConfig.php');

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM compid");
            <title>Computer Record</title>  
        </head>
        <body><thead>
                    <tr>
                                          <th id='time'> </th>
                                            <th>Computer ID</th>
                                            <th id='time'>ComputerName</th>
                                            <th id='title'>Status</th>
                                            <th id='cost'>IP</th>
                                            <th id='size'>OS</th>
                                            <th id='author'>RAM</th>
                                                  <th id='author'>CPU</th>
                                                        <th id='author'>Machine Model</th>
                                                              <th id='author'>Serial Number</th>
                                                                    <th id='author' >Remarks</th>
                                                                          <th id='author'>Application</th>
                                                                          <th id='author'>User</th>
    <th id='author'>Delete</th>
    <th id='author'>Edit</th>
                    </tr></thead>
                    ";
                                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
                    echo"<tbody>";

          echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='Days[]' value=". $row['cid'] ."> </td>";               
      echo "<td>" . $row['cid'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['cname'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['stat'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['ip'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['os'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['ram'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['cpu'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['mmodel'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['snumber'] . "</td>";
      echo "  <td>" . $row['remarks'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td ><a href='App_List.php?cname=" . $row['cname'] . "'><img src='http://10.9.57.129:8888/SGSComputer5.3/FINAL/images/view.png' style='border-style: none'></a></td>";
          echo "<td><a href='User_List.php?cname=" . $row['cname'] . "'><img src='http://10.9.57.129:8888/SGSComputer5.3/FINAL/images/user_group.png' style='border-style: none'></a></td>";
      echo "<td><a href='del_Main.php?ID=" . $row['ID'] . "' onclick='return checkDelete()'><img src='http://10.9.57.129:8888/SGSComputer5.3/FINAL/images/erase.png' style='border-style: none'></a></td>"; 
       echo "<td><a href='Edit_Main.php?ID=" . $row['ID'] . "'><img src='http://10.9.57.129:8888/SGSComputer5.3/FINAL/images/edit.png' style='border-style: none'></a></td>";               
                                    }
    echo "</table>";?>
?>
```

This is User_List.php

```
   if(isset($_GET['cname'])) {
$txt= $_GET['cname'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user Where cname like '$txt'");
 echo"<body bgcolor='#696969'>
          <input type='submit' value='Export'  method='post'>
         </head>";
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>

<th>Users</th>
<th> </th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $one = $row['cname']; 
echo "<tr>";

echo "<td>" . $row['user'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td><a href='User_List.php?ID=" . $row['ID'] . "' onclick='return checkDelete()'><img src='http://10.9.57.129:8888/SGSComputer5.3/FINAL/images/erase.png' style='border-style: none'></a></td>";  echo "</tr>";


echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

This is my delete button in table  how can i update the page this is the delete.php:

```
if(isset($_GET['ID'])) {

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM `SGSCOMP`.`user` WHERE `user`.`ID` = ".$_GET["ID"]);
}
```

How to get back to the User List

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Why have you tagged `javascript`? What exactly is this script doing? What is the expected result, and what is the actual result?

Comment: You have to redirect the page!

Comment: In **delete.php**, at very end after executing query give `header("location:User_List.php")`

Answer (score 0):

To go back to `User_List.php`, you can simply use `header()`. This will redirect users after running `mysqli_query`.

You should check if the row was deleted successfully by using `mysqli_affected_rows()`. This will return the number of rows affected, ie if 1 row was deleted, it will return 1.

```
if(isset($_GET['ID'])) {

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM `SGSCOMP`.`user` WHERE `user`.`ID` = ".$_GET["ID"]);

    if (mysqli_affected_rows($conn) > 0) {
        header("Location:User_List.php");
        exit;
    } else { 
        // row was not deleted successfully
    }

}
```

More information on `header()` at http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_header.asp.

> For `User_Main.php`, it should be:

You cannot put `<?php` tags inside of `<?php` tags.

```
<?php
  include_once('dbConfig.php');

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM compid");

?>

        <title>Computer Record</title>  
    </head>
    <body><thead>
                <tr>
                                      <th id='time'> </th>
                                        <th>Computer ID</th>
                                        <th id='time'>ComputerName</th>
                                        <th id='title'>Status</th>
                                        <th id='cost'>IP</th>
                                        <th id='size'>OS</th>
                                        <th id='author'>RAM</th>
                                              <th id='author'>CPU</th>
                                                    <th id='author'>Machine Model</th>
                                                          <th id='author'>Serial Number</th>
                                                                <th id='author' >Remarks</th>
                                                                      <th id='author'>Application</th>
                                                                      <th id='author'>User</th>
<th id='author'>Delete</th>
<th id='author'>Edit</th>
                </tr></thead>
<?php
                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
                echo"<tbody>";

      echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='Days[]' value=". $row['cid'] ."> </td>";               
  echo "<td>" . $row['cid'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['cname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['stat'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ip'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['os'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ram'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['cpu'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['mmodel'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['snumber'] . "</td>";
  echo "  <td>" . $row['remarks'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td ><a href='App_List.php?cname=" . $row['cname'] . "'><img src='http://10.9.57.129:8888/SGSComputer5.3/FINAL/images/view.png' style='border-style: none'></a></td>";
      echo "<td><a href='User_List.php?cname=" . $row['cname'] . "'><img src='http://10.9.57.129:8888/SGSComputer5.3/FINAL/images/user_group.png' style='border-style: none'></a></td>";
  echo "<td><a href='del_Main.php?ID=" . $row['ID'] . "' onclick='return checkDelete()'><img src='http://10.9.57.129:8888/SGSComputer5.3/FINAL/images/erase.png' style='border-style: none'></a></td>"; 
   echo "<td><a href='Edit_Main.php?ID=" . $row['ID'] . "'><img src='http://10.9.57.129:8888/SGSComputer5.3/FINAL/images/edit.png' style='border-style: none'></a></td>";               
                                }
echo "</table>";
?>
```

> For `User_List.php`

You didn't close `if(isset($_GET['cname'])) {`, with another curly bracket.

> For `delete.php`, it should be:

There's no need to concat the string as it's reductant.

```
if(isset($_GET['ID'])) {

   $result = mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM `SGSCOMPuser` WHERE `userID` = '$_GET["ID"]');
}
```

Comment: Nothing displayed @luweiqi the user_list.php have query  where like $txt comes in other php page so he can gets data

Comment: @Jyrwyn It's most probably due to other parts of your code

Comment: I have history.back at delete.php but its not updated the data I deleted is still exist because its just history.back is there any code I can relpad the page at only once I tried Reload page but its looping @luweiqi

Comment: @Jyrwyn Can you update your question to include that part of your code?

Comment: I includ the main page

Comment: idid include the main page

Comment: @Jyrwyn Did you remove `history.back`? Cause `header()` should work

Comment: I did but nothing appears the php needs to get value from the main_page.php but I don't know how to make it

Comment: @Jyrwyn Updated answer, it should work, you don't need to concat the string, as it's reductant

Comment: Yes I did remove it but nothing appears check my query at user_list he needs a data where the page can search in database    if(isset($_GET['cname'])) {
$txt= $_GET['cname'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user Where cname like '$txt'")

Comment: It's 2 different tables compid in main_page.php and user for the user_list.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do a [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) redirect directly after the update-query in your `delete.php`.

```
header("location:User_List.php")
```

This will redirect the user back to `User_List.php`.

> header() is used to send a raw HTTP header. See the » HTTP/1.1 specification for more information on HTTP headers.

Comment: The User_List.php query that gets data comes from another page so the database have where like $txt